# firebase authentication in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to support a react codebase being added to an existing mvc website.  The react developer wants to use Firebase for authentication purely to verify that the user's email is correct.  The login page has the user enter their email, which kicks off a request to Firebase to send an email to the user.  Clicking the link in the email opens a link on the firebase system which redirects the page to the local redirect, which includes the email address, apiKey, mode, and oobCode.

The problem I have with this is that I don't know of a way to keep a user from simply typing in that redirect url themselves.

It's not a serious issue for most of the visitors but for about 1% we need to make sure the user can't simply edit the url.

It seems like overkill to use firebase, but it's better than writing our own email verification system.

Comment: What exactly is the problem if the user does what you're saying?  Is this a situation you've tested?

Comment: Ok.  User A visits the site, uses his email address, receives an email from firebase, and clicks the link.  How he can access his account.  In order to access someone else's local (non-firebase) account, all he has to do is enter the same redirect url with a different email address.  Pretty much makes security a joke there.  Remember, it's only using firebase to verify the email address.  No actual data is stored on firebase.

Comment: So, you've verified that you can simply replace the email address and access the other account?

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it well.  The firebase authentication works fine, but it comes back to our site with the redirected url we gave it.  Once it's redirected back to use, controller on our side takes the querystring to figure out who they are.  If the user edits that url and inputs an entirely different email address, our controller has no way to tell.  At that point, the controller is going to look up local data (not in firebase) and return it to the user.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the documented way to integration Firebase Authentication.  Did you follow the guide?  You're supposed to use the API to find out when someone is finally logged in, not look at URLs or query strings.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out he's using the new passwordless authentication process that was introduced in March 2018.  https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/using-passwordless-signup-with-firebase-on-the-web/    So I'm not sure how secure just reading the cookie by the controller could be.

Comment: Well, one of the main points of Firebase Auth is (obviously) security.  I don't understand all the details here, but the assumption should be that it's secure, and that the browser participates in that internally.  There is likely more going on than you can see in the URL, probably an auth token stored in the browser.  If you can prove that it's not secure, file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: This isn't a question about firebase's security.  It's about after that.